Floating point error while using HDL coder in MATLAB
I have a simple function to perform QPSK modulation on a given signal.
function modulatedSig = qpskMod1(in_signal)

modulatedSig = fi(complex(zeros(10000,1)), 1, 12, 9);
a = 0.707;
b = -0.707;
%symbol_map = [complex(a,a), complex(-a,a), complex(a,-a), complex(-a,-a)];


for i = int16(1):2:int16(20000)
    if in_signal(i) == 0 && in_signal(i+1) == 0
        modulatedSig((i+1)/2) = complex(a,a);
    elseif in_signal(i) == 0 && in_signal(i+1) == 1
        modulatedSig((i+1)/2) = complex(b,a);
    elseif in_signal(i) == 1 && in_signal(i+1) == 0
        modulatedSig((i+1)/2) = complex(a,b);
    else
        modulatedSig((i+1)/2) = complex(b,b);
    end
end


end

I am using the HDL coder in MATLAB to covert the function to Verilog. The fixed point code generated by MATLAB is as shown,
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%                                                                          %
%          Generated by MATLAB 24.1 and Fixed-Point Designer 24.1          %
%                                                                          %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%#codegen
function modulatedSig = qpskMod1_fixpt(in_signal)

fm = get_fimath();

modulatedSig = fi(complex(zeros(10000,1)), 1, 12, 9);
a = fi(0.707, 1, 12, 9, fm);
b = fi(-0.707, 1, 12, 9, fm);
%symbol_map = [complex(a,a), complex(-a,a), complex(a,-a), complex(-a,-a)];


for i = int16(1):2:int16(20000)
    if in_signal(i) == fi(0, 0, 1, 0, fm) && in_signal(i+1) == fi(0, 0, 1, 0, fm)
        modulatedSig(fi_div_by_shift((i+1), 1)) = complexx(a,a);
    elseif in_signal(i) == fi(0, 0, 1, 0, fm) && in_signal(i+1) == fi(1, 0, 1, 0, fm)
        modulatedSig(fi_div_by_shift((i+1), 1)) = complexx(b,a);
    elseif in_signal(i) == fi(1, 0, 1, 0, fm) && in_signal(i+1) == fi(0, 0, 1, 0, fm)
        modulatedSig(fi_div_by_shift((i+1), 1)) = complexx(a,b);
    else
        modulatedSig(fi_div_by_shift((i+1), 1)) = complexx(b,b);
    end
end


end



function c = complexx(varargin)
    coder.inline( 'always' );
    if nargin==2
        re = varargin{ 1 };
        im = varargin{ 2 };
        if isfi( re ) && isfi( im )
            % Choose wider type
            NT = fixed.aggregateType( re, im );
            c = complex( fi( re, NT ), fi( im, NT ) );
        else
            c = complex( re, im );
        end
    elseif nargin==1
        c = complex( varargin{ 1 } );
    end
end


function y = fi_div_by_shift(a,shift_len)
    coder.inline( 'always' );
    if isfi( a )
        nt = numerictype( a );
        fm = fimath( a );
        nt_bs = numerictype( nt.Signed, nt.WordLength + shift_len, nt.FractionLength + shift_len );
        y = bitsra( fi( a, nt_bs, fm ), shift_len );
    else
        y = a / 2 ^ shift_len;
    end
end

function fm = get_fimath()
    fm = fimath('RoundingMethod', 'Floor',...
         'OverflowAction', 'Wrap',...
         'ProductMode','FullPrecision',...
         'SumMode','FullPrecision');
end


Whenever I run the step for HDL code generation I get the following error message,

qpskMod1_fixpt:7    Error   Floating-point data type found at Function 'qpskMod1_fixpt' (#1.404.416), line 7, column 10 Function 'div' (#41.7021.7022), line 218, column 34 Function 'ixfun' (#39.1781.1795), line 47, column 14 Function 'div' (#41.6834.6924), line 212, column 9 Function 'div' (#41.5018.5043), line 150, column 9 Function 'div' (#41.974.994), line 29, column 9 Function 'rdivide_helper' (#40.1207.1230), line 34, column 5 Function 'qpskMod1_fixpt' (#1.1992.2009), line 60, column 13 Function 'qpskMod1_fixpt' (#1.792.817), line 19, column 22. in MATLAB code. To generate floating-point HDL code, set 'Advanced > Check for presence of reals in the generated HDL code' to 'None' or 'Warning', set 'Optimizations > Aggressive Dataflow Conversion' to 'true', and set 'Floating-Point > Library' to 'Native Floating Point'.

What changes should I make in my original function to prevent this error from occurring? I can't change the fixed point code generated by MATLAB because I don't have necessary permissions to do so.

Hi and Welcome to DSP.SE. The nature of your question is rather a Matlab question than a pure signal processing question. Consider to ask it directly in the matlab forum. However I would recommend to take care of the fixpoint conversion yourself. See this information from matlab best-practices-for-converting-matlab-code-to-fixed-point
